# How to bind data from internal database to devExpress gridcontrol

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, devexpress, silverlight-5.0

I am an newbie, programming on devExpress silverlight application.
I created a database by adding `new item`, and i added `Database1.mdf` in to solution `trial.web`.
When i create my project it had 2 solutions: `DXSilverlightApplication1` (contains `MainPage.xaml/.cs`) and `Trial.Web` (contains `DXSilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx/.html`).

I really have no idea how to bind data from an MDF file to devExpress grid control.
MY data base has 2 columns: Name and ID only.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table adapter that does a basic SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM YourDatabaseName
```

Once you have done that on the top right corner of your GridControl select the data source
(in our example the basic `SELECT` statement). Hope this helps.